# How can I get my sys.argv command line to work properly in my python turtle program

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

So I am currently working on a turtle drawing program and I want the user to input a size on the command line using sys.argv, in order to draw a certain scene style. However everytime I input a command I get this error: (in this example I typed in small)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'small' is not defined
```

Here is what my code looks like, feel free to edit it in in any way to help the program. Anything helps, thanks!

```
from turtle import *
from random import randint



HELP_MESSAGE = ("Please set the size on the command line\n"
"Valid options are: small, medium, and large\n"
f"Example: small") 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print(HELP_MESSAGE)
        sys.exit(1)

    size = sys.argv[1]
    if size == "small":
        setup (400,250)
        sky_stars(5, -200, 200, 0, 125)
        draw_landscape(400, 250, -200, -50)
        the_moon(25, -150, 50, -140, 50)
        mountain_1(150, -200, -50)
        mountain_2(150, 50, -50)
        mountain_3(200, -80, -50)
    elif size == "medium":
        setup (800,500)
        sky_stars(10, -400, 400, 0, 250)
        draw_landscape(800, 500, -400, -100)
        the_moon(50, -300, 100, -280, 100)
        mountain_1(300, -400, -100)
        mountain_2(300, 100, -100)
        mountain_3(400, -160, -100)
    elif size == "large":
        setup (1600,1000)
        sky_stars(20, -800, 800, 0, 500)
        draw_landscape(1600, 1000, -800, -200)
        the_moon(100, -600, 200, -560, 200)
        mountain_1(600, -800, -200)
        mountain_2(600, 200, -200)
        mountain_3(800, -320, -200)
    else:
        print(ERROR_MESSAGE)
        sys.exit(1)


speed(0)
bgcolor('Black')



def stars(side_length): 
    ''' Draws and colors the shape of the stars in the sky . '''
    color('yellow')
    begin_fill()
    for i in range (5):
        forward(side_length)
        right(144)
    end_fill()
    
def landscape(length, height):
    ''' Draws a simple rectangle at bottom of the screen for the landscape.'''
    for i in range(2):
        forward(length)
        right(90)
        forward(height)
        right(90)
        
def sky_stars(side_length, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    ''' Randomly inserts the previously defined stars in the night sky.'''
    for i in range(40):
        x = randint(x1, y1)
        y = randint(x2, y2)
        stars(side_length)
        penup()
        goto(x, y)
        pendown()
        ht()
    
def draw_landscape(length, height, x1, y1):
    '''Draws the rectangle, previously defined, at the correct positioning which is the bottom of the screen. '''
    penup()
    goto(x1,y1)
    pendown()
    color('dark green')
    begin_fill()
    landscape(length, height)
    end_fill()


def the_moon(radius, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    ''' Draws 2 circles, 1 in white and 1 in black, to create the effect of the halfmoon in the sky.'''
    penup()
    goto(x1,y1)
    color('white')
    begin_fill()
    circle(radius)
    end_fill()
    penup()
    goto(x2, y2)
    pendown()
    color('black')
    begin_fill()
    circle(radius)
    end_fill()

def mountain_1(side_length, x1, y1):
    ''' Draws and colors the mountain on the left side of the screen.'''
    penup()
    goto(x1,y1)
    pendown()
    color('grey')
    begin_fill()
    for i in range(3):
        forward(side_length)
        left(120)
    end_fill()

def mountain_2(side_length, x1, y1):
    ''' Draws the mountain to the right side of the screen. '''
    penup()
    goto(x1,y1)
    pendown()
    begin_fill()
    for i in range(3):
        forward(side_length)
        left(120)
    end_fill()

def mountain_3(side_length, x1, y1):
    ''' Draws, colors and scales up the size of the mountain in the middle of the screen.'''
    penup()
    goto(x1,y1)
    pendown()
    color('dark grey')
    begin_fill()
    for i in range(3):
        forward(side_length)
        left(120)
    end_fill()
```

Comment: The code you provided does not cause the error you gave. Ensure that you're supplying a [mre].

Comment: (it's already not _minimal_; to meet that part of the spec, you'd remove all the drawing parts and include _only_ the command-line parsing bits and enough support code to let them reach the error).

Comment: ...are you maybe typing `small` at a Python REPL, instead of at a shell? You should be running something like `./yourscript small` _in your UNIX shell_ (like bash), not in Python. But in any event, the question should have enough details that I shouldn't be needing to guess what kind of prompt you're typing the command into.

Answer (score 0):

I actually did not run into the name error when I tested out your code.  However, I did run into an issue with calling the functions with the if **name** == "**main**": test at the beginning of the file.  Usually, the methodology for using that test is to have that at the end of the file and have it call a function called "main()".

Following is a revised version of your code.

```
from turtle import *
from random import randint
import sys         # Moved this import up here as well

HELP_MESSAGE = ("Please set the size on the command line\n"
"Valid options are: small, medium, and large\n"
f"Example: small") 

def main():             # Instead of performing the "main test here - ran into issues finding the supporting functions otherwise"
    
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print(HELP_MESSAGE)
        sys.exit(1)

    size = sys.argv[1]
    if size == "small":
        setup (400,250)
        sky_stars(5, -200, 200, 0, 125)
        draw_landscape(400, 250, -200, -50)
        the_moon(25, -150, 50, -140, 50)
        mountain_1(150, -200, -50)
        mountain_2(150, 50, -50)
        mountain_3(200, -80, -50)
    elif size == "medium":
        setup (800,500)
        sky_stars(10, -400, 400, 0, 250)
        draw_landscape(800, 500, -400, -100)
        the_moon(50, -300, 100, -280, 100)
        mountain_1(300, -400, -100)
        mountain_2(300, 100, -100)
        mountain_3(400, -160, -100)
    elif size == "large":
        setup (1600,1000)
        sky_stars(20, -800, 800, 0, 500)
        draw_landscape(1600, 1000, -800, -200)
        the_moon(100, -600, 200, -560, 200)
        mountain_1(600, -800, -200)
        mountain_2(600, 200, -200)
        mountain_3(800, -320, -200)
    else:
        print(ERROR_MESSAGE)
        sys.exit(1)

sleep()

speed(0)
bgcolor('Black')

def stars(side_length): 
    ''' Draws and colors the shape of the stars in the sky . '''
    color('yellow')
    begin_fill()
    for i in range (5):
        forward(side_length)
        right(144)
    end_fill()
    
def landscape(length, height):
    ''' Draws a simple rectangle at bottom of the screen for the landscape.'''
    for i in range(2):
        forward(length)
        right(90)
        forward(height)
        right(90)
        
def sky_stars(side_length, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    ''' Randomly inserts the previously defined stars in the night sky.'''
    for i in range(40):
        x = randint(x1, y1)
        y = randint(x2, y2)
        stars(side_length)
        penup()
        goto(x, y)
        pendown()
        ht()
    
def draw_landscape(length, height, x1, y1):
    '''Draws the rectangle, previously defined, at the correct positioning which is the bottom of the screen. '''
    penup()
    goto(x1,y1)
    pendown()
    color('dark green')
    begin_fill()
    landscape(length, height)
    end_fill()


def the_moon(radius, x1, y1, x2, y2):
    ''' Draws 2 circles, 1 in white and 1 in black, to create the effect of the halfmoon in the sky.'''
    penup()
    goto(x1,y1)
    color('white')
    begin_fill()
    circle(radius)
    end_fill()
    penup()
    goto(x2, y2)
    pendown()
    color('black')
    begin_fill()
    circle(radius)
    end_fill()

def mountain_1(side_length, x1, y1):
    ''' Draws and colors the mountain on the left side of the screen.'''
    penup()
    goto(x1,y1)
    pendown()
    color('grey')
    begin_fill()
    for i in range(3):
        forward(side_length)
        left(120)
    end_fill()

def mountain_2(side_length, x1, y1):
    ''' Draws the mountain to the right side of the screen. '''
    penup()
    goto(x1,y1)
    pendown()
    begin_fill()
    for i in range(3):
        forward(side_length)
        left(120)
    end_fill()

def mountain_3(side_length, x1, y1):
    ''' Draws, colors and scales up the size of the mountain in the middle of the screen.'''
    penup()
    goto(x1,y1)
    pendown()
    color('dark grey')
    begin_fill()
    for i in range(3):
        forward(side_length)
        left(120)
    end_fill()

if __name__ == "__main__":      # Moved the startup here and call the "main" function.
    main()
```

With that, I launched the program manually in my terminal as follows:

```
@Dev:~/Python_Programs/Scene$ python3 Scene.py medium
```

That resulted in the following image.

[image: Sample Image]

Anyway, give those suggested tweaks a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: That's great you got it to work, I'm using thonny so maybe there is something wrong on my end. I still can't get it to work, however your help is greatly appreciated.